# Is there any API for determining the physical address from virtual address in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-address-space

Is there any API for determining the physical address from virtual address in Linux operating system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the physical address of a variable from user-space in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440385/how-to-find-the-physical-address-of-a-variable-from-user-space-in-linux)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate and @Vlad answer is actually helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28987409/1163019

Answer (score 40):

Kernel and user space work with virtual addresses (also called linear addresses) that are mapped to physical addresses by the memory management hardware. This mapping is defined by page tables, set up by the operating system.

DMA devices use bus addresses. On an i386 PC, bus addresses are the same as physical addresses, but other architectures may have special address mapping hardware to convert bus addresses to physical addresses.

In Linux, you can use these functions from `asm/io.h`:

- virt_to_phys(virt_addr);
- phys_to_virt(phys_addr);
- virt_to_bus(virt_addr);
- bus_to_virt(bus_addr);

All this is about accessing ordinary memory. There is also "shared memory" on the PCI or ISA bus. It can be mapped inside a 32-bit address space using ioremap(), and then used via the readb(), writeb() (etc.) functions.

Life is complicated by the fact that there are various caches around, so that different ways to access the same physical address need not give the same result.

Also, the real physical address behind virtual address can change. Even more than that - there could be no address associated with a virtual address until you access that memory.

As for the user-land API, there are none that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder why there is no user-land API. What is the complexity in providing that API in Linux ? Is there any script or tool that provides the physical address corresponding to the virtual address ?

Comment: @S.Man: It doesn't matter whether there is a user-land API for this or not. The thing that is more important is - what can that user-land API do for you? In my opinion, it is useless. And so many other people think I believe. Why would one invest their time and efforts to do useless things?

Comment: As for the user-land API, 1 way I can think about is to code the kernel space functions, and let the user space to query (get values). 

The motivation to get the physical address may be for some malware detection usage.

Note to others: Do not think it is useless, just because you cannot think of a use for it.

Comment: Note that `virt_to_phys` only works for `kmalloc` memory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128487/895245

Comment: I lloked at the virt_to_phy function and all it does is to subtract IDNET_ADDRESS instead of doing a pagetable walk, Im assuming that not a bug (otherwise would have probably been discovered by now) can you explain this?

Comment: @user405725 As a comment on its usefulness, this is a necessary feature for heterogeneous systems where the CPU uses virtual memory but an attached accelerator that uses the same memory may only have physical addressing. For the CPU to share data with the accelerator it would need to write it in its (virtual) address space and then provide a physical address to the accelerator.

Answer (score 38):

**`/proc/<pid>/pagemap` userland minimal runnable example**

*virt_to_phys_user.c*

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <fcntl.h> /* open */
#include <stdint.h> /* uint64_t  */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* size_t */
#include <unistd.h> /* pread, sysconf */

typedef struct {
    uint64_t pfn : 55;
    unsigned int soft_dirty : 1;
    unsigned int file_page : 1;
    unsigned int swapped : 1;
    unsigned int present : 1;
} PagemapEntry;

/* Parse the pagemap entry for the given virtual address.
 *
 * @param[out] entry      the parsed entry
 * @param[in]  pagemap_fd file descriptor to an open /proc/pid/pagemap file
 * @param[in]  vaddr      virtual address to get entry for
 * @return 0 for success, 1 for failure
 */
int pagemap_get_entry(PagemapEntry *entry, int pagemap_fd, uintptr_t vaddr)
{
    size_t nread;
    ssize_t ret;
    uint64_t data;
    uintptr_t vpn;

    vpn = vaddr / sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    nread = 0;
    while (nread < sizeof(data)) {
        ret = pread(pagemap_fd, ((uint8_t*)&data) + nread, sizeof(data) - nread,
                vpn * sizeof(data) + nread);
        nread += ret;
        if (ret <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    entry->pfn = data & (((uint64_t)1 << 55) - 1);
    entry->soft_dirty = (data >> 55) & 1;
    entry->file_page = (data >> 61) & 1;
    entry->swapped = (data >> 62) & 1;
    entry->present = (data >> 63) & 1;
    return 0;
}

/* Convert the given virtual address to physical using /proc/PID/pagemap.
 *
 * @param[out] paddr physical address
 * @param[in]  pid   process to convert for
 * @param[in] vaddr virtual address to get entry for
 * @return 0 for success, 1 for failure
 */
int virt_to_phys_user(uintptr_t *paddr, pid_t pid, uintptr_t vaddr)
{
    char pagemap_file[BUFSIZ];
    int pagemap_fd;

    snprintf(pagemap_file, sizeof(pagemap_file), "/proc/%ju/pagemap", (uintmax_t)pid);
    pagemap_fd = open(pagemap_file, O_RDONLY);
    if (pagemap_fd < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    PagemapEntry entry;
    if (pagemap_get_entry(&entry, pagemap_fd, vaddr)) {
        return 1;
    }
    close(pagemap_fd);
    *paddr = (entry.pfn * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)) + (vaddr % sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    uintptr_t vaddr, paddr = 0;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s pid vaddr\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    pid = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    vaddr = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    if (virt_to_phys_user(&paddr, pid, vaddr)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: virt_to_phys_user\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    };
    printf("0x%jx\n", (uintmax_t)paddr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/873737bd1fc6e5ee0378f21e9df1c52e3f61e3fb/userland/virt_to_phys_user.c).

Usage:

```sh
sudo ./virt_to_phys_user.out <pid> <virtual-address>
```

`sudo` is required to read `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` even if you have file permissions as explained at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345915/how-to-change-permission-of-proc-self-pagemap-file/383838#383838

As mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247716/895245 Linux allocates page tables lazily, so make sure that you read and write a byte to that address from the test program before using `virt_to_phys_user`.

**How to test it out**

Test program:

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { I0 = 0x12345678 };

static volatile uint32_t i = I0;

int main(void) {
    printf("vaddr %p\n", (void *)&i);
    printf("pid %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid());
    while (i == I0) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("i %jx\n", (uintmax_t)i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The test program outputs the address of a variable it owns, and its PID, e.g.:

```
vaddr 0x600800
pid 110
```

and then you can pass convert the virtual address with:

```sh
sudo ./virt_to_phys_user.out 110 0x600800
```

Finally, the conversion can be tested by using `/dev/mem` to observe / modify the memory, but you can't do this on Ubuntu 17.04  without recompiling the kernel as it requires: `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=n`, see also: [How to access physical addresses from user space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040303/accessing-physical-address-from-user-space/45127890#45127890) Buildroot [is an easy way](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat) to overcome that however.

Alternatively, you can use a Virtual machine like QEMU monitor's `xp` command: [How to decode /proc/pid/pagemap entries in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux/45126141#45126141)

See this to dump all pages: [How to decode /proc/pid/pagemap entries in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux/45126141#45126141)

Userland subset of this question: [How to find the physical address of a variable from user-space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440385/how-to-find-the-physical-address-of-a-variable-from-user-space-in-linux)

**Dump all process pages with `/proc/<pid>/maps`**

`/proc/<pid>/maps` lists all the addresses ranges of the process, so we can walk that to translate all pages: [/proc/[pid]/pagemaps and /proc/[pid]/maps | linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284810/proc-pid-pagemaps-and-proc-pid-maps-linux/45500208#45500208)

**Kerneland `virt_to_phys()` only works for `kmalloc()` addresses**

From a kernel module, `virt_to_phys()`, has been mentioned.

However, it is import to highlight that it has this limitation.

E.g. it fails for module variables. [`arc/x86/include/asm/io.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/arch/x86/include/asm/io.h#L109) documentation:

> The returned physical address is the physical (CPU) mapping for
> the memory address given. It is only valid to use this function on
> addresses directly mapped or allocated via `kmalloc()`.

Here is [a kernel module that illustrates that](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/0677dbd4b582d1a913462d75caad0abf21e87f32/kernel_module/virt_to_phys.c) together with an [userland test](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/0677dbd4b582d1a913462d75caad0abf21e87f32/rootfs_overlay/virt_to_phys.sh).

So this is not a very general possibility. See: [How to get the physical address from the logical one in a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252063/simplest-way-to-get-physical-address-from-the-logical-one-in-linux-kernel-module) for kernel module methods exclusively.

Comment: -1. I tried this. In some cases it has spurious trailing zeros which makes the answer wrong. [Here](https://fivelinesofcode.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-translate-virtual-to-physical.html) is a correct program.

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 thanks for the comment, if you can give an example of when those trailing zeroes happen and what they look like, that would also be great.

Comment:  Oops. I mistakenly thought the program is supposed to output only the PFN, but it actually outputs the whole physical address. The program works correctly: +1 upvoted.

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 ah, thanks for confirming. Don't hesitate to tell me if you find anything  that seems wrong.

Comment: Weird I have r permission to `pagemap` as a regular user, are you aware of a sysctl config that can restrict the access to root-only? EDIT: It seems that I can only access `pagemap` of processes that I own.

Comment: Why is data of type uint32_t in your function pagemap_get_entry? What if I am on a 32 bit system? Same for the present flag and pfn. You're shifting 63 times. Asking because my conversions seem to not be correct, perhaps because I am using a beagle bone black not x86.

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn also no idea, but try: hexdump the thing and reverse engineer the format, or look at Linux kernel source. Let me know if you find something out.

Answer (score 19):

As answered before, normal programs should not need to worry about physical addresses as they run in a virtual address space with all its conveniences. Furthermore, not every virtual address has a physical address, the may belong to mapped files or swapped pages. However, sometimes it may be interesting to see this mapping, even in userland.

For this purpose, the Linux kernel exposes its mapping to userland through a set of files in the `/proc`. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt). Short summary:

1. `/proc/$pid/maps` provides a list of mappings of virtual addresses together with additional information, such as the corresponding file for mapped files.
2. `/proc/$pid/pagemap` provides more information about each mapped page, including the physical address if it exists.

[This website](http://www.eqware.net/Articles/CapturingProcessMemoryUsageUnderLinux/index.html) provides a C program that dumps the mappings of all running processes using this interface and an explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 9):

The suggested C program above usually works, but it can return misleading results in (at least) two ways:

1. The page is not present (but the virtual addressed is mapped to a page!). This happens due to lazy mapping by the OS: it maps addresses only when they are actually accessed.
2. The returned PFN points to some possibly temporary physical page which could be changed soon after due to copy-on-write. For example: for memory mapped files, the PFN can point to the read-only copy. For anonymous mappings, the PFN of all pages in the mapping could be one specific read-only page full of 0s (from which all anonymous pages spawn when written to).

**Bottom line is, to ensure a more reliable result:** for read-only mappings, read from every page at least once before querying its PFN. For write-enabled pages, write into every page at least once before querying its PFN.

Of course, theoretically, even after obtaining a "stable" PFN, the mappings could always change arbitrarily at runtime (for example when moving pages into and out of swap) and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder why there is no user-land API.

Because user land memory's physical address is unknown.

Linux uses demand paging for user land memory. Your user land object will not have physical memory until it is accessed. When the system is short of memory, your user land object may be swapped out and lose physical memory unless the page is locked for the process. When you access the object again, it is swapped in and given physical memory, but it is likely different physical memory from the previous one. You may take a snapshot of page mapping, but it is not guaranteed to be the same in the next moment.

So, looking for the physical address of a user land object is usually meaningless.