# ARM platform, how to convert virtual address to physical address in kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

As we know, on ARM platform, 16MB space is reserved for kernel modules below PAGE_OFFSET.
If I write a module and define a global variable, then how I get its phisical address?
It is obvious that I get a wrong physical address using virt_to_phys function.

Comment: Are you asking about Linux?  You should probably tag your question so, if that's the case.

Comment: Related to but not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252063/simplest-way-to-get-physical-address-from-the-logical-one-in-linux-kernel-module

Answer (score 1):

If virt_to_phys won't work for you, you can use the MMU to do a V=>P mapping, see [Find the physical address of exception vector table from kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275718/find-the-physical-address-of-exception-vector-table-from-kernel-module/19290502)

Comment: I am wondering why those kernel developer guys did not provide such function as virt_to_phys?

Comment: `virt_to_phys` is a simple macro.  For code in the kernel proper, there is a one-to-one mapping of virtual to physical memory; simple math can get the address.  For other memory, the physical page is semi-random and a lookup must be done.