# Getting physical address from /proc/[pid]/pagemap

Tags: linux

I am told that I can find the physical address corresponding to a virtual address using `/proc/[pid]/pagemap`.

I read that this **pagemap** file is an array of 64-bit entries, with bits 0-54 corresponding to the page frame number.  I don't know how to make the leap from this to translating virtual to physical.  Partially, I don't know how to find the entry I want in this file; nobody seems to specify how they are indexed.

Also, I don't know if the PFN is virtual or physical.  And I don't know what to do with the PFN, regardless.  How can I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284810/proc-pid-pagemaps-and-proc-pid-maps-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode /proc/pid/pagemap entries in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the VA by the page size (4096 normally), use that as an offset into /proc/self/pagemap. Then take that number (the page), multiply by the pagesize (4096), and offset that by your VA%4094.

Larry