# Segmentation fault in a 'C' program

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to understand when any why a segmentation fault is generated. 
I wrote a small program which writes to an invalid random address.

I do not see a segmentation fault with this program -

```
 int main (void)
    {
    int c = 6;

    *(&c + 1000) = 5;

    printf ("0x%llx - %d\n", (unsigned long)&c, c);

    return 0;
    }
```

which outputs:

```
$ gcc segmentationFault.c
$ ./a.out
0x7ffc2f709b5c - 6
$
```

But, I get a seg fault with below code -

```
int main (void)
{
    int c = 6;

    *(&c + 3000) = 5;

    printf ("0x%llx - %d\n", (unsigned long)&c, c);

    return 0;
}
```

which produces:

```
$ gcc segmentationFault.c
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Any explanation please?

Comment: `UB` and `UB`. and *I do not see a segmentation fault* is one of the possible behavior under `UB`

Comment: Use a debugger!

Comment: The "undefined" in "undefined behaviour" should be a hint, that the result is ... well, undefined. Don't expect anything specific.

Comment: Have you tried reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya While using a debugger is in general a good start, I don't see how it could help answering the question.

Comment: The OS allocates memory in chunks which dimension is related to the processor paging dimension. In the first attempt the resulting address seems to be inside the allocated page, the second one is definitely outside and hits the guard page. Considering that paging generally use 4kb pages this should be reasonable.

Comment: @Frankie_C, Is the memory allocated to stack segment dependent on page size? I'm running this program on linux.

Comment: @UnClaimed in a system almost all memory is allocated through the Memory Manager using the paging mechanism. The stack isn't an exception apart for the fact that usually it grows downward.

Comment: When you run across the freeway, there is no guarantee that you get hit by a car every time. That doesn't mean that running across the freeway is safe and something you should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

A segmentation fault happens when your program accesses memory it isn't allowed to access. In your example, `c+1000` could still be accessible to your program, while `c+3000` isn't any more. However, since it's undefined behavior even `*(c+1)` could cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks tstenner,Is there a way I could find the memory space accessible to my program?

Comment: I think `(&c+1)` might be OK because C does not make reading one beyond the end of an array undefined behavior. The dereference will certainly bring trouble, though. Probably a moot point/distinction... Also see [Access element beyond the end of an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1021021/608639).

Comment: @jww Does a variable count as a single element array?

Comment: @jww But `c` isn't an array. So definitely UB, right?

Answer (score 3):

There are different points in your question: one is what C language mandates, one is what your implementation does.

For the C language part: you are invoking Undefined Behaviour because as `c` is a single variable, `&c` is a pointer to the beginning of an array of size 1. So dereferencing `&c + i` is UB for any `i != 0`. UB means that from a language point of view anything can happen from returning an int to the definitive machine dead. Nothing more can be said here.

For the implementation part, a seg fault is an attempt to read an address that resides is a page that is not bound to the process in a system that gives pages of memory (with possibly *virtual* addresses, meaning a table mapping addresses in process space to addresses in physical memory). On Linux, the `/proc/{pid}/maps` and `/proc/{pid}/pagemaps` give information about the mapping for a process. More details on it on the following SO pages:

- [Is there any API for determining the physical address from virtual address in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5748492/3545273)
- [/proc/[pid]/pagemaps and /proc/[pid]/maps | linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284810/3545273)