# observe physical address content

Tags: linux, memory, mmap

I  compile and run the pagemap_dump.c from here :

[/proc/[pid]/pagemaps and /proc/[pid]/maps | linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284810/proc-pid-pagemaps-and-proc-pid-maps-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and another application attach a exist shared memory and every time I run pagemap_dump ,  the shared memory's physical address is really the same (virtual memory address is different each time I observe) :

```
./pagemap_dump.exe 2135  <== 2135 is pid  
./pagemap_dump.exe 5864  <== 5864 is pid 
./pagemap_dump.exe 5110  <== 5110 is pid
```

the output :

```
7fabb37e1000 54edde 0 1 0 1 /dev/shm/memtest.shared
7f0040fa1000 54edde 0 1 0 1 /dev/shm/memtest.shared
7ffbd2869000 54edde 0 1 0 1 /dev/shm/memtest.shared
```

these 3 application attach memtest.shared and their physical address are all 0x54edde in my linux , 
then I try to access the contents from /dev/mem in this 
physical address :

[How to access physical addresses from user space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040303/how-to-access-physical-addresses-from-user-space-in-linux)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <phys_addr> <offset>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    off_t offset = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    size_t len = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    // Truncate offset to a multiple of the page size, or mmap will fail.
    size_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    off_t page_base = (offset / pagesize) * pagesize;
    off_t page_offset = offset - page_base;

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY|O_SYNC);
    unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char *) mmap(NULL, page_offset + len, PROT_READ , MAP_SHARED, fd, page_base);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Can't map memory");
        return -1;
    }

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", (int)mem[page_offset + i]);

    return 0;
} // main
```

chown root testz1.exe

chmod 4775 testz1.exe

```
./testz1.exe  5565918  16    <=== 0x54edde = 5565918
```

I got  Can't map memory: Operation not permitted

```
./testz1.exe 54edde 16
```

I got some thing not like "hello world" what I strcpy to 
/dev/shm/memtest.shared when I create it .

Since I seems to get the physical address of /dev/shm/memtest.shared , how can I get the right way to get the contents from /dev/mem of this physical address ?!

Edit  :

After download devmem2.c and  run :

```
./devmem2.exe 0x54edde w
```

get the following message :

/dev/mem opened.
Error at line 75, file devmem2.c (1) [Operation not permitted]

Look like 0x54edde is not a physical address as I expect , but Why it happened?!
pagemap_dump.c  really show  the physical address of /dev/shm/memtest.shared 
for all processes which attach it the value 0x54edde  ,  then Why 
devmem2.c  can not access it right ?!

Comment: does the result differ with sudo?

Comment: @Nikita ,  I  use sudo or chown root && chmod 4775  to run this application , both get the same result , and  not "hello world" .