# Accessing HDMI hardware register in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, embedded

I am trying to access the HDMI hardware registers on a Phytec MIRA board using C. This is my first real step into embedded programming.

The memory address for the Design ID register, according to the [i.MX 6 Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/IMX6DQRM.pdf?fasp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf), is 0x120000 (See page 1568).

I wrote some code to try to access this register, and it just gives a segmentation fault when I try to dereference the pointer.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction please?

Minimal reproducing code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
  uint8_t const volatile * const HDMI_DESIGN_ID = (uint8_t const volatile * const)(0x120000);
  printf("Design ID: %u\n", *HDMI_DESIGN_ID);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access from user space ?

Comment: That would only have a chance of working if memory mapping is turned off.  What processor and what OS?

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes I am running the program in user space.

Comment: @Neztor I'd take a shot and say that the registers are in memory region where only the `OS` has access. Trying to access this will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @stark i.MX 6 Processor, running linux

Comment: @TonyTannous If the memory is in a region where only the OS has access, how can I read or write to it?

Comment: You could possibly implement a new system call which returns values of addresses in kernel space.

Comment: @TonyTannous I just did some googling, is this what you mean?

`int hdmi_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
HDMI_DESIGN_ID = mmap((void*)(0x120000), sizeof(uint8_t), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, hdmi_fd, 0);
`

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote and I think there should be easier ways than implementing a new syscall. What you wrote here is not what I meant.

Comment: @TonyTannous Then what did you mean?

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494812/convert-physical-address-to-virtual-in-linux

Comment: @TonyTannous Thanks I'll keep an eye on it