# Virtual address to physical address and reverse in android linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, virtual

I'm trying to transform virtual address to physical address and map this physical address to virtual address with android linux kernel environment.

I can modify kernel code.  So I tried next flow.

1. `malloc()` in android user space native binary not app
2. Transform `va` from `malloc()` to `pa` using the guide
   [Is there any API for determining the physical address from virtual address in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748492/is-there-any-api-for-determining-the-physical-address-from-virtual-address-in-li)
3. Pass `pa` to a system call function I made.
4. Re-map received `pa` to `va` in linux kernel space using `ioremap()`
5. Read value using `readl()` or `ioread32()`

But it's not working now.

1. The `va` to `pa` logic is in above link; in my native binary, below is the pseudo-code.

```
    int main(){
        char *va=malloc(100);
        memset(va, "ttttt", ...)
        uintptr_t paddr;
        vir_to_phys_user(&paddr, getpid(), va);
        syscall(sys_readpa, (unsigned long)paddr);
    }
```

2. system call function

```
    void sys_readpa(unsigned long pa){
        void __iomem* mapped_add = ioremap(pa);
        printk("%c", readl(mapped_add));
        printk("%c", ioread32(mapped_add));
    }
```

My code has similar logic:

- I define `va` in user space and calculate `pa` from `va`.
- I set `va` to "ttttt".
- Pass `pa` to linux kernel space using syscall.
- Remap this `pa` to `va` in kernel space.
- Read `va` in kernel space and expect the value to be "ttttt"

I don't know the `va` to `pa` logic is correct.  But it returns an address not failure.

But when syscall is called, kernel panic occur - e.g. "dereference for 0000000 address", and other kinds of errors.  I checked `pa` in syscall is same with the one in user space.

My purpose of this try is study.  I just wonder this implementation is possible if I can modify kernel code too but I met with an obstacle.

Please let me know what is problem or it's impossible?  If needed, I'll update more detail code or specific error message.

---

I add detail errors and my debug log.

My user space log

```
: vitrual address : 0xf079c000
: 0xf079c000 -> 0xa4a8a000
```

I pass 0xa4a8a000 to syscall.

dmesg

```
[   96.794448] accepted pa : 00000000a4a8a000
[   96.794473] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   96.794500] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 11644 at arch/arm64/mm/ioremap.c:58 __ioremap_caller+0xc0/0xcc
[   96.794519] Modules linked in:
[   96.794552] CPU: 6 PID: 11644 Comm: mt Not tainted 4.14.113 #1
[   96.794590] Call trace:
[   96.794611] [<0000000000000000>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x2b8
[   96.794632] [<0000000000000000>] show_stack+0x18/0x24
[   96.794655] [<0000000000000000>] dump_stack+0xa0/0xdc
[   96.794676] [<0000000000000000>] __warn+0xbc/0x164
[   96.794695] [<0000000000000000>] report_bug+0xac/0xdc
[   96.794713] [<0000000000000000>] bug_handler+0x30/0x8c
[   96.794732] [<0000000000000000>] brk_handler+0x94/0x150
[   96.794751] [<0000000000000000>] do_debug_exception+0xd4/0x170
[   96.794769] Exception stack(0xffffff8010fdbc10 to 0xffffff8010fdbd50)
[   96.794787] bc00:                                   0000000000000000 0000000000000004
[   96.794805] bc20: 00e8000000000f07 ffffff8008358714 000000000000000c 0000000000002d7c
[   96.794822] bc40: ffffffc0119630e7 5b20205d38343434 0000000000000000 0000000000000001
[   96.794839] bc60: 0000000000000001 00000000bab00000 0000000000000000 0000000080000000
[   96.794856] bc80: ffffff800b18d000 0000000000000082 00000000000564c8 0000000000000074
[   96.794873] bca0: 0000000000000074 00e8000000000f07 00000000a4a8a000 0000000000001000
[   96.794890] bcc0: ffffff8008358714 0000000000000000 0000000000000011 000000000000018f
[   96.794908] bce0: 000000000000018e ffffff8009316000 ffffffc8767edf80 ffffff8010fdbe80
[   96.794926] bd00: ffffff80081fe124 ffffff8010fdbe50 ffffff80081fe188 0000000020400145
[   96.794943] bd20: 0000000000000034 7cebe7b2cf849500 0000007fffffffff ffffff8009316000
[   96.794961] bd40: ffffff8010fdbe80 ffffff80081fe188
[   96.794978] [<0000000000000000>] el1_dbg+0x18/0x74
[   96.794995] [<0000000000000000>] __ioremap_caller+0xc0/0xcc
[   96.795014] [<0000000000000000>] __ioremap+0x10/0x1c
[   96.795035] [<0000000000000000>] sys_readpa+0x78/0xfc
[   96.795055] Exception stack(0xffffff8010fdbec0 to 0xffffff8010fdc000)
[   96.795072] bec0: 00000000a4a8a000 0000000028bf4d08 0000000000000003 00000000f079c000
[   96.795090] bee0: 0000000000000000 00000000a4a8a000 0000000000000000 000000000000018e
[   96.795107] bf00: 00000000f09afd94 00000000f09d2b99 00000000ae6c9e84 00000000ae6a261e
[   96.795124] bf20: 00000000ff921bf0 00000000ff921be0 00000000ae5f7b27 0000000000000000
[   96.795142] bf40: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   96.795159] bf60: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   96.795176] bf80: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   96.795195] bfa0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   96.795212] bfc0: 00000000f091ce20 0000000060000010 00000000a4a8a000 000000000000018e
[   96.795229] bfe0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   96.795247] [<0000000000000000>] __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
[   96.795265] ---[ end trace 91e76f3be7c0b9bd ]---
[   96.795418] ioremap return null
```

Comment: Hi, I've reformatted and corrected spelling errors for readability; if you could add the specific error messages that would help you get answers to your question.

I've added code formatting markdown to better format the code/pseudo-code examples - see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found fix.
ioremap have a check logic for validation of address.
This function is for reserved address but it tring to map address that's already mapped to a process.
So, I modify the check logic in ioreamp and it works well.