# Using /proc/[pid]/pagemap

Tags: linux, process, proc

I am aware that there is a little information regarding the pagemap file here.  But nobody seems to indicate how to reference entries in the file.  Is it offset by virtual address?  Can I take a virtual address VA and simply lseek to offset VA?  Or is it by page?  If so, how do I retrieve the page number, as maps simply lists them in order.  I am trying to translate between virtual and physical addresses, and lseek'ing with the virtual address as the offset always returns the same number, no matter where I seek to.

Thanks

@leeduhem: Yes I have.  Here's the relevant part:
 3. Open /proc/pid/pagemap and seek to the pages you would like to examine.
 4. Read a u64 for each page from pagemap.

That doesn't help me.  It wants me to seek to the page, but how do I know where the entry for the page is?

Comment: Have you read [the document of pagemap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode /proc/pid/pagemap entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool that will help you to get information you need from the pagemap file.

http://fivelinesofcode.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-translate-virtual-to-physical.html

Comment: why `offset` is not used in this function?
I refer to `offset` as the 3rd filed in a `maps` entry

Comment: Is is the case that `maps` entry `offset` is the offset of the particular file/device+inode that is backing the mapping?

Comment: Paschalis, I didn't quite get your question, but are you referring to "Bits 5-54  swap offset if swapped" from here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt ?

Comment: Hmm... I don't even get the question I asked you some time ago. It seems that I was expecting `offset` of the `maps` entry to be used for indexing the pagemaps file.

Answer (score 2):

You divide the virtual address by the pagesize (normally 0x1000 or 4096) and use that to index in /proc/self/pagemap.  After the division, that's known as the PFN, or page frame number.

Larry